# Swift 5 breaking my native module export, with error Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods

Tags: objective-c, swift5, swift4.2

I have a swift native module, which i have written in Swift 4.2, Now i have updated my xcode, and it is breaking my code with error

> Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed
>   to have +load methods

If i am not exporting my module its working fine, But if i am exporting my module with `@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MFobSDK, NSObject)`
its breacking my Code. If anyone have any idea why its happening please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue.
If you will notice , when you run the app on a real device it will work fine.
The problem is in the pods, do pod update.

Comment: doesn't work for me. Still have the same issue after doing "pod repo update"

Comment: @Krishna try doing rm -rf Pods and then pod install.

Comment: I did try. Still no luck in resolving the issue.